# How to append my own string in return data of facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook-apps

I have tried to use the,

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(){
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request'
    }, requestCallback);
  }
```

for creating invite friends request, but its not return to me for email of my friends and also not getting idea to how to append my own string with that accessible notification link?

I am stuck to get email and changing to request data, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: This is JavaScript and not Java, I've retagged it.

Answer (score 0):

The response contains some kind of information in string. Using javascript, it is quite easy to append the string using String Concatination. For eg:

```
target_string = response_string + 'your_string';
```

PS: any improvements are appreciate.